# Row Count Nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, nhibernate

I'm building a web app where i need to get the number of rows on one table in the database, according to some restrictions, so my code looks like something like this:

```
db.Query<DutyDoctor>()
  .Where(x => x.Duty.Time.ToUpper() == periodo.ToUpper())
  .Where(x => x.Doctor.Id == doctorId)
  .Count(x => x.EnterDatetime.Year == ano || x.ExitDatetime.Year == ano);
```

I've read that doing query like this would be poor at performance, because it's goinig to get all the objects, create a list of objects and than just give me the length of the list, then, as I just want the number of rows that obey those restrictions, I've seen some exepmles like this:

```
 db.QueryOver<DutyDoctor>()
      .Where(x => x.Duty.Time.ToUpper() == periodo.ToUpper())
      .Where(x => x.Doctor.Id == doctorId)
      .Where(x => x.EnterDatetime.Year == ano || x.ExitDatetime.Year == ano)
      .RowCount();
```

It did not work, i've got an exeption, so I'd like to ask how would I make tha second exemple work and how could i improve the performance of the first one, making it just get the row count from the database, using the `db.Query()` insted of `db.QueryOver()`.

*`db` is of type `NHibernate.ISession`

Comment: "It did not work, i've got an exeption". Do you think *maybe* the text of the exception is important?

Comment: the exeption was:
variable 'x' of type 'MedSolutions.DAO.Models.DoctorDuty' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

Comment: What you say about NH will load all the objects, I think that depends only on how you've written your query. See deferred execution of linq. I think the way you've written is ok, you may want to check the sql query executed with a profiler.

Comment: I've checked with a profile and the first exemple is actualy doing the right thing, it's a 'select count(*)' that is being executed by NHibernate.

Thank you anyway.

Comment: Take a look at projections. Project EnterDatetime.Year and ExitDatetime.Year, then do count.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using projections for getting the row count:

```
public int GetNumberOfRecordsFromTable()
{
  return session.QueryOver<YourTable>()
            .Select(Projections.RowCount())
            .FutureValue<int>()
            .Value;
}
```